# mySQL LIKE Query on pipe

Tags: mysql, sql, pipe, delimited

I'm trying to get a count for **pics_india** and **pics_other** in mysql using LIKE operator.

I have a keywords piped (pics_india,pics_other,pics_other_france) i.e

```
pics_other_france  
pics_other  
pics_other|pics_other_france|pics_other|pics_other_france
pics_other_france|pics_other_france  
pics_other_france|pics_india|pics_india|pics_other_france|pics_india
```

my query looks like:

```
if(medmas.mf_mm_keywords LIKE '%pics_india%','1','0')AS Pics_Ind,
if(medmas.mf_mm_keywords LIKE '%|pics_other' OR 'pics_other|%' OR '%pics_other%' OR '%|pics_other_france' OR 'pics_other_france|%' OR '%pics_other_france%','1','0')AS Pics_Other
```

If **pics_other_france|pics_india or |pics_india|pics_other_france** the case,I would like to credit to **pics_india** only, additionally **pics_other** count is also wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve your problem is to normalize your table (instead of storing a list in a single field, you should store multiple rows). If you can't change your database structure, you could use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

First you have to replace | with commas, and you could use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function, then you can call FIND_IN_SET:

```
FIND_IN_SET('pics_india', REPLACE(mf_mm_keywords, '|', ','))
```

your query then could be like this:

```
SELECT
  if(FIND_IN_SET('pics_india', REPLACE(medmas.mf_mm_keywords,'|',','))>0, '1', '0') AS Pics_Ind,
  if(
    (FIND_IN_SET('pics_other', REPLACE(medmas.mf_mm_keywords,'|',','))>0
     OR
     FIND_IN_SET('pics_france', REPLACE(medmas.mf_mm_keywords,'|',','))>0),
    '1', '0') AS Pics_Ind,
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thanks fthiella..I have tried as you suggested,now i am getting zero counts for both Pics_ind & Pics_other.